# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception running on emulator nexus5 api27

Tags: android, flutter

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not create service of type DefaultUserHomeScopedCompileCaches using UserHomeScopeServices.createCompileCaches().

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Please tell me a solution to overcome this problem.

Comment: Have you tried to re-download your dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Run `flutter clean` in terminal or from android studio and try running the app again.